# mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: python, mysql

I have this code:

```
query = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, sp.amount, cp.amount, sp.monthly, sp.date_ FROM set_payment7777 sp JOIN customers_payments7777 cp ON cp.customer_VAT = sp.customer_VAT WHERE sp.date_ = (SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 GROUP BY customer_VAT) GROUP BY sp.customer_VAT"""
mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
    #do something
```

but I get the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more
> than 1 row

Comment: It's self explanatory. SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 GROUP BY customer_VAT typically wouldn't return a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You have several  customer_VAT  then your subquery return more than a row  .. for avoid this you could use a join on the subquery

```
query = """SELECT sp.customer_surname, sp.amount, cp.amount, sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
    FROM set_payment7777 sp 
    INNER JOIN customers_payments7777 cp ON cp.customer_VAT = sp.customer_VAT 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 
        GROUP BY customer_VAT
    ) t on t.customer_VAT =  sp.customer_VAT 
    
    GROUP BY sp.customer_VAT"""
```

anyway you have a main select without aggregation function then you should avoid an improper use of group by.  In this case  use DISTINCT if you need not repeated  result

```
query = """SELECT DISTINCT sp.customer_surname, sp.amount, cp.amount, sp.monthly, sp.date_ 
    FROM set_payment7777 sp 
    INNER JOIN customers_payments7777 cp ON cp.customer_VAT = sp.customer_VAT 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 
        GROUP BY customer_VAT
    ) t on t.customer_VAT =  sp.customer_VAT"""
```

Comment: that seems good the only problem is that I am getting a syntax error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
                        SELECT MAX(date_) FROM set_payment7777 
              ' at line 4

Comment: answer  updated  missing JOIN

Comment: I am still getting a weird error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.customer_VAT' in 'on clause'

Comment: update your question and add the exact code you are using